# How to check only one radio button at a time (others disable)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, radio-button, silverlight-5.0

I am working in silverlight c# and i have situation where i create radio buttons programatically. My code to do so is this:

```
 Grid childGrid = CreateChildGrid(); 
 int NumberOfRadioButton =0;

 RadioButton[] RadioBut= new RadioButton[5];
 int count = 0;
 foreach (var item in param.Component.Attributes.Items)// this  param.Component.Attributes.Items value is 4 in fact.
 {                 
     NumberOfRadioButton++;
     RadioBut[count] = new RadioButton();
     RadioBut[count].GroupName = item;
     RadioBut[count].Content = item;
     sp.Children.Add(RadioBut[count]);
     count++;
 }
```

**Problem:** The problem is it checks all the button where as i want only one button checked at a time . I mean if one checked the others must be disable.

Could some one please help me to achieve my target ? Thanks a lot.

**Note:** I am using silverlight to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the [`GroupName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of all `RadioButtons` to the same, so they will be "grouped", meaning only one of them can be selected at a time.

So this line:

```
rbs[count].GroupName = item;
```

Should be something like this:

```
rbs[count].GroupName = "MyRadioButtonGroup";
```

Of course the string can be anything, as long as it is the same for all `RadioButtons`.

Comment: But i already have this in my code. Please see rbs[count].GroupName = item;

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to assign these radio buttons to a common group. Check [Radio Button Group Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
RadioButton[] rbs = new RadioButton[5];
rbs.GroupName = "Add your common groupname here"; // added code
 int count = 0;
```